# insert form values in table in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to insert values in database.i don't know what is the problem my form values are not inserted successfully. when i click on create user button my form will open up in a modal popup window.

And i don't know why my form validation also not working properly.

Here is my Controller:

```
  public function createOrgUsers() {

    //Validating Name Field
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'firstname', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'lastname', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');




    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        redirect('Organisation/view_organisations');
    } else {
        //Setting values for tabel columns
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
            'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
        );

        //Transfering data to Model
        $this->Org_model->orgUsers($data);
        $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
        //Loading View
        redirect('Organisation/editOrg');
    }
}
```

Here is my model:

```
function orgUsers($data) {
    // Inserting in Table(users)
    $this->db->insert('users', $data);
}
```

Here is my view popup:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="createUser" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="createUser" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content" id="modal-content">
                            <form class="form-horizontal" id="admin-create-user" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Organisation/createOrgUsers" method="post" role="form">

                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create New User</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Username:</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                                            <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username" >                            
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <small></small>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="inputFirstname" class="col-sm-4 control-label">First Name:</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                                            <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" id="inputFirstname" placeholder="First Name" >                             
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <small></small>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="inputLastname" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Last Name:</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                                            <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" id="inputLastname" placeholder="Last Name" >
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <small></small>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 control-label">E-mail:</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                                            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" >
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <small></small>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Password:</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <small></small>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                <input type="hidden" name="form_submission" value="admin_registration">                                         

                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit3" >Create New User</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Can anyone help me where i did mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are any error?

Comment: no its not displaying any errors

Comment: have you loaded your form_validation library

Comment: `users` table's structure add it in your question

Comment: yes pradeep i loaded in autoload

Comment: your users table drop of it's structure?what it mean

Comment: show me your model and users table's structure, thanks!

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov  i created new users table now its inserting but  form validation is not working

Comment: why did you assume that form validation is not working?

Comment: You are asking after insert data popup model open?

Comment: when i click on submit button with out giving any values the page is refreshing.it should not refresh rite?the popup has to stay there rite?

Comment: yes ramesh..after i open model popup if i click on submit button its not working

Comment: After insert check your `url`, it is in same page?

Comment: yes i have create user button in editorg page so i am redirecting to same page only

Comment: when i click on submit button the popup is going off and its displaying ediorg page

Comment: Okay in ur modal print ur data like this `echo'<pre>'; print_r($data); exit;`

Comment: `function orgUsers($data) {
   echo'<pre>'; print_r($data); exit;
    $this->db->insert('users', $data);
}`  Like this. Bro Tamil huh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171306/discussion-between-suresh-and-ramesh-s).

Comment: "why did you assume that form validation is not working?" ... indeed. you just redirect hence there is no way of knowing what is going on. you need to plan for obvious "errors" - such as those caused by form validation.

Answer (score 0):

As your chat you want to show button click modal popup open and show user datas by his/her `id`.

My suggestion is use `Ajax`

```
<a href='<?php echo base_url()?>"Organisation/editOrg?id=$org->id' title='Edit' class='open_modal btn btn-default' id="userView">
<i class='fas fa-edit'></i>
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="ShowUser" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="createUser" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content" id="modal-content">
                <form class="form-horizontal" id="admin-create-user" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Organisation/createOrgUsers" method="post" role="form">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create New User</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Username:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username" value="">                            
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <small></small>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

AJAX:

```
$('#userView').click(function(){
var id = <?php echo $_GET['id'];
    $.ajax({
        url: "contoller_name",
        type: 'POST',
        data: "id=" + id,
        success: function(returndata){
              $('#ShowUser').modal('show');
              // to create id and pass the all data via id
              var  usename = returndata.username;

              $('#inputUsername').val(usename);
        }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
    function contoller_name()
{
    $id = this->input->post('id');

    $data = $this->modal_name->modelFuncName($id);
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')
             ->set_output(json_encode($data));
}
```

Model:

```
function modelFuncName($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table_name');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```